# the first train to London

Tags: sentence-usage

Could you say if both sentences are correct? 
Which sentence construction is used more frequently?

> Do you know what time the first train goes to London tomorrow morning?

vs

> Do you know when the first train to London is tomorrow morning?

TIA

Comment: Both are good, also "When is the first train to London tomorrow?" One assumes the first train will be in the morning.

Comment: Or "Do you know the time of the first train to London tomorrow?" There are so many variants, it's impossible to say which is used most frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is good, it is easy to say and to understand.

The second seems clumsy to my UK English senses. After several attempts at reading it I realised that a pause (or separation) is needed after the "is" when reading the question out loud. The main question concludes with the "is". The "tomorrow morning" restricts the question. When writing I would put a comma between "is" and "tomorrow".